# Права на создание каталога, подкатологов и файлов без возможности удаления

Tags: chmod

Всем привет!

Не могу понять с настройками доступа к каталогам и файлам, нужна помощь.

Суть в чем: есть пользователь, у которого домашняя папка (для удобства) это /var/www/html.
Пользователь коннектится к этой папке по фтпc (vsftpd).
Есть обработка внешняя, которая позволяет коннектиться к указанной дирректории и создавать там подкаталоги и файлы.
Необходимо дать такие разрешения этому пользователю, чтоб он мог создавать каталоги и файлы, но не мог их после этого удалять (удалять может только root).
Как это организовать?